Why does RSpec Rails generate mailer fixtures?
I executed this command:
rails g mailer users/confirmations confirm_email

It generated this file at spec/fixtures/users/confirmations/confirm_email:
Users::Confirmations#confirm_email

Hi, find me in app/views/users/confirmations/confirm_email

What is this file for?

Mailer fixtures provide predefined data for testing, allowing you to test your mailers consistently with the same set of data. This ensures that your tests are repeatable and reliable.
By using fixtures, you can isolate the mailer tests from the rest of your application. This means that changes in other parts of your application will not affect the results of your mailer tests.

What about if I use dynamic data? Like translations, and tokens?
